# How to round off a float value in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me how to round a float value in extjs4.1? For example, if I have the value 24.536, I need to round it to 24.54. If I have 24.534, I need to round it to 24.53.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you realy want round number, use it:

```
number = Math.round(number * 100) / 100;
```

### Extend

If you want show rounded number - you may use ExtJs numbe format tools. Try this:

```
//Set these once, right after Ext.onReady
Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator = ' ';
Ext.util.Format.decimalSeparator = '.';

//Then this should round your number correctly:
Ext.util.Format.number(12345.00, '0,000.00'); //output 12 345.67
```

Comment: thanks for your help want to display two digit floating number .if it is 0 its not displaying can u tell how to display two digit floating no